# Python how to convert a list of dict to a list of tuples

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples

I have a list of dict that looks like this:

```
list=[{u'hello':['001', 3], u'word':['003', 1], u'boy':['002', 2]}, 
     {u'dad':['007', 3], u'mom':['005', 3], u'honey':['002', 2]} ]
```

What I need is to iterate on my list in order to create list of tuples like this:

```
new_list=[('hello','001', 3), ('word','003',1), ('boy','002', 2)
           ('dad','007',3), ('mom', '005', 3), ('honey','002',2)]
```

NOTE! the numbers with the zeros ('001',003'... and so on) must be considerated as a string.

Is there anybody whom can help me?

Comment: What if a key occurs in both dictionaries?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. You should show at least minimal effort to solve this problem yourself.

Comment: If a key occurs two times it must be writed two times.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem This does not seem to be a problem here.

Comment: @CosimoCuriale Which Python version are you using?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use list comprehension for that:

```
new_list = [(key,)+tuple(val) for dic in list for key,val in dic.items()]
```

Here we iterate over all `dic`tonaries `in list`. For every `dic`tionary we iterate over its `.items()` and extract the `key` and `val`ue and then we construct a tuple for that with `(key,)+val`.

Whether the values are strings or not is irrelevant: the list comprehension simply copies the reference so if the original elements were `Foo`s, they remain `Foo`s.

Finally note that the dictionaries are unordered, so the order is undetermined. However if a dictionary `d1` occurs before a dictionary `d2`, all the elements of the first will be placed in the list before the tuples of the latter. But the order of tuples for each individual dictionary is not determined.

Answer (score 2):

List-comprehension one-liner for **Python 3.5+**:

```
my_list=[{u'hello':['001', 3], u'word':['003', 1], u'boy':['002', 2]},
         {u'dad':['007', 3], u'mom':['005', 3], u'honey':['002', 2]}]

result = [(k, *v) for f in my_list for k,v in f.items()]

# [('word', '003', 1), ('hello', '001', 3), ('boy', '002', 2), ('dad', '007', 3), ('honey', '002', 2), ('mom', '005', 3)]
```

PS: Do not use the variable name `list` since it is a python built-in.

For older versions of Python see answer by @WillemVanOnsem which does not make use of the starred expressions (`*v`).

Comment: Those `u`-strings indicate that the OP is using Python 2, so the star expansion in `(k, *v)` won't work for them.

Comment: Yeh, this is nice, if you have Python 3.5+

Answer (score 2):

```
list=[{u'hello':['001', 3], u'word':['003', 1], u'boy':['002', 2]}, 
     {u'dad':['007', 3], u'mom':['005', 3], u'honey':['002', 2]} ] 

 >>> [map(lambda (k,v): (k,)+tuple(v), dictionary.iteritems()) for dictionary in list]

[[(u'boy', '002', 2), (u'word', '003', 1), (u'hello', '001', 3)], [(u'dad', '007', 3), (u'honey', '002', 2), (
u'mom', '005', 3)]]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

If your values in the dictionary are always lists of length 2, you could do:

```
new_list = [ (key, value[0], value[1]) for dict in list for key, value in dict.iteritems() ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you don't care about having the output re-coded as ASCII as your example shows, that you don't care about preserving order and that you want to merge items in case they appear more than once across the union of the listed dictionaries, this code example should work:

```
>>> input_list = [
...    {u'hello': ['001', 3], u'word': ['003', 1], u'boy': ['002', 2]},
...    {u'dad': ['007', 3], u'mom': ['005', 3], u'honey': ['002', 2]}] 
...
>>> temporary_dict = {}
>>> output_list = []
>>> for dictionary in input_list:
...     for key in dictionary.keys():
...         if key in temporary_dict:
...             temporary_dict[key] += dictionary[key]
...         else:
...             temporary_dict[key] = dictionary[key]
...
>>> for key in temporary_dict.keys():
...     output_list.append(tuple([key] + temporary_dict[key]))
...
>>> print(output_list)
[(u'dad', '007', 3), (u'boy', '002', 2), (u'word', '003', 1),
 (u'honey', '002', 2), (u'mom', '005', 3), (u'hello', '001', 3)]
```

Note how I first concatenate the keys from all of the listed dictionaries into a `temporary_dict` and then I iterate over that dictionary, making a concatenated list of the dictionary `key` as well as that key's values (`temporary_dict[key]`), and append them to a new output list.

Please let me know if any of my assumptions are incorrect.