# How to convert dictionary list as tuple list

Tags: python

I working on function. i have total_list from which i need to pull out unique records as tuple list for Department-JobRole. I did it as dictionary list but I can't make as tuplelist

```
total_list = sorted(list(zip(lista_Monthlyincome, lista_EducationField, lista_Education, lista_Department, lista_TotalWorkingYears, lista_JobRole)))

# [(1009, 'Medical', 1, 'Research & Development', 1, 'Research Scientist'), (1051, 'Life Sciences', 2, 'Research & Development', 0, 'Research Scientist')

def edufield_Dep_JR_dic(lista, educationfield):
    all_found = []
    for element in total_list:
        if element[1] == str(educationfield):
            add_to_all_found = True
            for element2 in all_found:
                for key, value in element2.items():
                    klucz = key
                    wartosc = value
                if klucz == element[3] and wartosc == element[5]:
                    add_to_all_found = False
                    break
            if add_to_all_found:
                 all_found.append({element[3]: element[5]}) 
    return all_found
print(edufield_Dep_JR_dic(total_list, 'Medical'))
```

in next step i need to add more objects to create unique tuplelists for Department-JobRole-Education-TotalWorkingYears-MonthlyIncome. Probably(i'm begginner) i can't make it with dictionary because dictionary have 2 object key:value so i can take only 2 objects

Comment: What do you mean by *dictionary list*?

Comment: Do you mean list of tuples and list of dictionaries by *tuple list* \ *tuplelist* and *dictionary list*?

Comment: Have you thought about using pandas for what you are trying? Seems like a good idea to me

Comment: By dictionaries list i mean: [{'Research & Development': 'Research Scientist'}, {'Sales': 'Sales Representative'}, {'Research & Development': 'Laboratory Technician'}]. This is my output. i need create: [('Research & Development', 'Research Scientist')]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python how to convert a list of dict to a list of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42249655/python-how-to-convert-a-list-of-dict-to-a-list-of-tuples)

Comment: @Shino commonly, this is called a 'list of dictionaries', to avoid missinterpretation.

Comment: @Shino Is this what you want  `all_found.append((element[3],  element[5]))`?

Comment: I'm working to solve it with pandas.